# Java applet doesn't work in the browser - using image file

Tags: java, applet

I have a java applet which demonstrates some filters. I have a predefined path for an example image and the user is able to choose an own picture.

I can't use new File because I am working in the browser and hav no access to the users storage. So I use a byte array to store my image data which was cropped and resized by using the library Thumbnailator:

```
public byte[] resize(String filepath) throws IOException{
        ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        this.setBackground(Color.RED);
//      System.out.println("public File resize(String filepath)...");

        Thumbnails.of((new URL(filepath)))
        .size(256, 256)
        .outputQuality(1.0f)
        .outputFormat("jpg")
        .toOutputStream(outStream);

        byte[] bosArray = null; 
        bosArray = outStream.toByteArray();

        return bosArray;
    }
```

that is the call of resize() in my init():

```
try {
            if (ONLINE){
                String fname = FILENAME;
                if(getCodeBase()!=null)
                    fname = getCodeBase() + FILENAME;

                input = resize(fname);
            } 
            else {
                inputF = resize(new File(FILENAME));
            }

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and FILENAME is defined as a field:

```
private static final String FILENAME = "mountains.png";
```

in another class ImagePanel I transfer the byte array into a BufferedImage:

```
public class ImagePanel extends JScrollPane {

private BufferedImage img;
private int width;
private int height;
private int[] histo;
private int[] normHisto; // normalized histogram
private int histogramHeight = 256;
private double variance;
private double expectation;

private int maxValueInHisto = 0;

/**
 * draw the image by using the stored BufferedImage
 */
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
}
```

.....

```
public ImagePanel(byte[] input) {

        try {
            //convert byte array back to BufferedImage
            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(input);
            img = ImageIO.read(in);

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        updateValues();
        this.setSize(width, height);
    }
```

And everything works in the applet viewer of Eclipse but in the browser.. nothing happens. It loads the applet and show nothing even no error message.

If I comment everything out and leave only the init of the applet and setting a background color -> it works. So that means that my html code should be fine

```
<applet width="1000" height="1000" code="filterpackage.mainView.class" archive="Thumbnailator-0.3.10-all.jar"/>
```

I tested it offline with Xampp and online in Chrome, Safari, Firefox but nothing happens, no error but no panel, no GUI.. nothing.

Do you know what is wrong? Or do you have a tip what I could try?

It would be great if someone can help me I spent so much time until now and I don't find the solution :(

Comment: `} catch (IOException e) {}`  For pity's sake, how do you expect to solve this when ignoring vital information?  Change that to `} catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace() }`.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Is the applet working? Any progress?

Comment: Not in the browser. It works only in the applet viewer of Eclipse :(

Answer (score 0):

if you run your applet from a local HDD the code like

```
getCodeBase() + FILENAME
```

definitely returns a local applet file path like a (in windows case)

> file: C:/.../...

So **file:** protocol is not the **http:** protocol so that may cause the problem with your *net* image to download according to the said path... Moreover, you say you have unsigned applet...

As a simple way, you should place the applet to the Tomcat webapp folder and run it in this manner

> http://localhost:8080/myappletpackage/applet.html

etc

If you have some additional question details do comment

Report that helps

Good luck

Comment: The applet is in my localhost directory:

http://localhost/PROJECT/WEB/FINAL/tool1.php

Do you mean that I should compile my applet from there? So that I put the whole project in a workspace in my localhost directory??

Comment: As a test, try it with Tomcat; And report what does the code getCodeBase() + FILENAME return? Use JRE console for this.

Comment: Or should I use the absolute path on the website (as a string) where it will be published later.. but then it won't compile in eclipse.

Comment: There is no need actually because getCodeBase() should return its location; The thing is about file download with applet; You are to use ByteArrayOutputStream to get your image so it means you are about to use IO; in this case you must know that applet can communicate (as download) from its native host only ; So you have to adapt it as much as you can not to sign it :)

Comment: "The applet is in my localhost directory: localhost/PROJECT/WEB/FINAL/tool1.php Do you mean that I should compile my applet from there? So that I put the whole project in a workspace in my localhost directory??" No, the applet must be already compiled and , as a resource, be placed to webapps folder; I do recommend to create a war file or a folder to store it

Comment: I am not sure if I really need a web app. I only want to load an image... It should be easier. I guess I have a stupid mistake somewhere else. There should be any kind of error message in the browser but .. nothing.

Comment: I got an error message in Safari

"ReaderArticleFinder aborting CandidateElement detection due to timeout"

What does it mean?

Comment: You'll have to provide a web app sandbox effect just because you use getCodeBase() to get your source image; If, otherwise, you want to get image file from a non-native host you'll have to sign the applet anyway... That's why I recommend to use Tomcat as to test it first... Could you tell what the code as getCodeBase() + FILENAME returns in your case and what is your applet absolute path?

Comment: file:/Users/Kristina/workspace/FFTFilterApplet2/bin/mountains.png

Comment: OMG.. You can't imagine how stupid my error was.. I didn't had the permission to open the file. I had to change the right for the file from 700 to 755. 

-.- so stupid.. I am sorry that I wasted your time. 
Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: As I was saying, the file:// protocol caused the problem :) So I am glad my answer was close to cope the problem :)